# Active Directory Site Level Group Policy Not Applied

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

In Active Directory we have multiple sites defined in AD Sites and Services and I can see the site is correctly assigned by verifying the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters\DynamicSiteName.

I've built proxy servers in each AD site and I want to use group policy to configure the computers in each site to use the proxy server in the same site.

When I link the group policy to an OU it's properly applied to the computer. When I link the group policy to a site, it's not applied. It doesn't even show up in gpresult after running gpupdate /force.

Does the group policy need to be linked to the domain and the site? What else could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: I created a new policy, linked it to the site, and then waited several days. It was applied successfully. Is it possible gpupdate /force doesn't force site policies to be applied immediately? Seems strange to me that a site policy would take longer to replicate and apply compared to a policy linked to an OU.

Answer (score 1):

A Site-level GPO would need to be linked at the site (which you have done).

Then - as you have multiple sites - you would have to wait a period of time (potentially a *long* period of time, if using default site replication intervals) for the link to replicate to the site (if it is not in the same site as the PDCe).

Then, you will need to ensure that the setting is not countered by any other GPO that may contain the same settings as the Site GPO.  A GPO linked at the site is among the first that are evaluated, and therefore most easily reverted by a later-evaluated conflicting policy linked to the domain or OU.

Just looking at your screenshot, you have the GPO link enforced - the one at the OU level - so you're *never* going to see the site GPO because it will always be overwritten by the one linked at the OU.

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't seem right. Enforcement changes the priority order, but I'd still expect to see both GPO's in the applied or ignored policies list even if individual settings get overwritten

Comment: If you run the GPMC and connect to a DC in the same site as the client do you see your Site linked GPO?